# Android - Save image by Google Drive/Photo doesn't work

Tags: android, android-image

In my app, user can choose an image, that I save in internal memory.

My code works perfecly if I choose an image that is in internal memory, but if I choose an image that is on the cloud (Drive or Photo) it doesn't work and it save an 0bit image.

The code is in a fragment.

This is a part of my code:

First, I choose the image with

```
                        Intent i = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Then, I save the image with

```
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Bitmap imageSelect = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        cursor.close();
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("images",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File myPath = new File(directory,"defaultwallpaper.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
            imageSelect.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try{
                if (fos!=null){
                    fos.close();
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And I have this errors:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the code and it works on my Nexus 5 with Android 6:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
/*String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
assert cursor != null;
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
imageSelect = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
cursor.close();*/
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you precise what "imageSelect" is refering to ?

Comment: @mattyU sorry, it's a my personal referer. It's a bitmap.